# Samba share accessible but access denied

Tags: samba

I have the following samba config (Centos7):

```
[global]
netbios name = HomeAssistant
server string = The HA File Center
workgroup = WORKGROUP
hosts allow =
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
remote announce =
remote browse sync =

[HOME ASSISTANT]
path = /home/homeassistant
comment = No comment
browsable = yes
read only = no
valid users =
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
public = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
force user = homeassistant
force create mode = 0777
force directory mode = 0777
hosts allow =
```

I have a homeassistant user and I have given it a samba password. When I connect in Windows to the share I see a "home assistant" folder.

But when I try to open it I get an access denied message.

The /home/homeassistant folder is configured as:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  4 homeassistant homeassistant 119 Jun 18 22:44 homeassistant
```

I'm not sure anymore what I'm missing at this point..

Comment: Have you tried disabling `selinux` first, rebooting, and then trying to connect?

Comment: @NasirRiley that did the trick!

Comment: I added an answer that gives a command where you don't need to disable `selinux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling `selinux` resolved things, but if you want to enable it, use the following command:

```
chcon -R -t  samba_share_t /home/homeassistant
```

That will allow the the directory to be accessed via `samba` through `selinux`. If `selinux` is enabled, you'll need to run that command on any `samba` shares. Be sure to restart the `smb` service afterwards.